# Custom exception for each invalid input value

Tags: php, exception, architecture

I have backend project in which there's own "parent-to-all exception" exists, something like this (also I have InvalidArgumentException derived from this exception):

```
class CaliException extends \Exception {
    private $caliCode;

    public function __construct(string $message = "", string $caliCode = self::UNDEFINED_CODE,
                                int $code = 0, Throwable $previous = null) {
        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);

        $this->caliCode = $caliCode;
    }

    function getCaliCode(): string {
        return $this->caliCode;
    }
}
```

It's clear from code above, that purpose of custom class is ability to keep string codes. Why do I need string codes? Because I have HTTP API which works in the following way:

1. Get JSON request
2. Do something
3. Produce JSON output with 'state' field which contains either code of a thrown exception or the "200" response. These state codes are quite useful for client which can distinguish different problems and react to them accordingly.

So there's a problem. System above produces code like this:

```
class UsernameFormatException extends InvalidArgumentException {
    public const USERNAME_FORMAT_UNDEFINED_CODE = "DM:USERCA:0001";

    public function __construct(string $message = "", string $calistoCode = self::USERNAME_FORMAT_UNDEFINED_CODE,
                                int $code = 0, \Throwable $previous = null) {
        parent::__construct($message, $calistoCode, $code, $previous);
    }
}

class PasswordFormatException extends InvalidArgumentException {
    public const PASSWORD_FORMAT_UNDEFINED_CODE = "DM:USERCA:0002";

    public function __construct(string $message = "", string $calistoCode = self::PASSWORD_FORMAT_UNDEFINED_CODE,
                                int $code = 0, \Throwable $previous = null) {
        parent::__construct($message, $calistoCode, $code, $previous);
    }
}

class InvalidLastActivityTimestampException extends InvalidArgumentException {
    public const INVALID_TIMESTAMP = "DM:USERCA:0003";

    public function __construct(string $message = "", string $calistoCode = self::INVALID_TIMESTAMP,
                                int $code = 0, \Throwable $previous = null) {
        parent::__construct($message, $calistoCode, $code, $previous);
    }
}

class InvalidCreationTimestampException extends InvalidArgumentException {
    public const INVALID_TIMESTAMP = "DM:USERCA:0004";

    public function __construct(string $message = "", string $calistoCode = self::INVALID_TIMESTAMP,
                                int $code = 0, \Throwable $previous = null) {
        parent::__construct($message, $calistoCode, $code, $previous);
    }
}
```

As seen, **for each invalid-argument-case I create new `CaliException`-derived exception**. I consider it as not cool. Is it good? How can I improve the code?

Bonus question: I read that I should throw `\InvalidArgumentException` when it's a programmer's mistake, so an exception must be not caught. But in my code there's no `\InvalidArgumentException` only my own version of this. Is it acceptable in the context of best practices and so on? And how to distinguish when it's a programmer's mistake and when it's mistake of user (invalid user input)? (After all, any invalid values passed to a function are invalid **inputs** relatively to this function)

Comment: If the code works and you're just asking us to review it, try posting it over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: _"how to distinguish when it's a programmer's mistake and when it's mistake of user"_ - If a programmer passes user data to a method that requires a specific type without validating it first, imho, it's still the programmers fault. If the user passes invalid data, you should return a 400 Bad Request (if it's an API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description it seem that you are actually making something like a REST API. Or at least something inspired by that concept.

The thing about exceptions of `InvalidArgumentException` is that, someone passed you  2nd or 3rd hand knowledge. Those exceptions **must** be caught, but not at *domain entity* or *service* layers. Instead, you catch them at the point .. well .. bootstrap-level, where you render a "pretty error json" response with all the headers and status codes.

As for your original question. Yes, having very specific exceptions is OK. Though, I would recommend instead of `PasswordFormatException` to name it `MalformedPassword`. Basically, ditche the `*Exeception` suffix, for the same reason as you do not have `class UserClass` suffix - it is worthless, PHP has namespaces now (since 2005 .. I think).

> <sub>This is just a quick'n'drunk comment. I am not even sure it answers your question.</sub>

Comment: "having very specific exceptions is OK" but this means I need to create new exceptions for almost every parameter, doesn't it?

Comment: @wcobalt you are looking at this wrong way. You do not make exceptions for "for parameter", but for violations of domain business rules.